# Getting sum with multiple constraints. In a sql file

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE Insurance (
    P_ID   varchar
    I_2011 decimal
    I_2012 decimal
    LAT    decimal
    LON    decimal
)
```

The line above is the schema of a table 'INSURANCE'. I am trying to add the contents of the column I_2012 with 2 conditions:

1. Any 2 or more P_ID's have the same I_2011 data
2. The LAT and LON must be distinct.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(I_2012)
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        LAT,
        LON,
        I_2012
    FROM
        INSURANCE
    GROUP BY
        I_2011
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: Tip: avoid `SELECT DISTINCT` outside of trivial queries and especially avoid it when using it with `GROUP BY` because `SELECT DISTINCT` is roughly equivalent to adding a wrapper `GROUP BY *` clause which makes it harder to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question.  One approach here is to actually find the `I_2011` values which fail the unique latitude/longitude test, and then retain all records which do not fail:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.I_2012)
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT I_2011
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY I_2011, LAT, LON
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.I_2011 = t2.I_2011
WHERE
    t2.I_2011 IS NULL
GROUP BY
    t1.I_2011;
```

The subquery aliased as `t2` will return all `I_2011` values which have two or more records with the same latitude longitude pair.  These are values we do not want in the result set.